# How to return a resultset from StoredProcedure using MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, output

I am writing a stored procedure using MySql which returns multiple rows using select statement.

My code is as below

```
drop procedure if exists GetAccounts; 
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAccounts() 
BEGIN 
DECLARE rowcount int;
SET @resultset = (SELECT * from requests where STATUS = "FAILURE" ;
END // 
DELIMITER
```

Any examples of how to return a resultSet in storedProcedure?

Thanks
Gendaful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAccounts; 
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAccounts() 
BEGIN 
DECLARE rowcount int;
    SELECT * from requests where STATUS = "FAILURE" ;
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want to return the resultSet to a DAO. So, I believe, I have to use output parameter, right?

Comment: Are you using any language, PHP for instance?

Comment: Ya, I am using hibernate to call this stored procedure and the expectation is this storedprocedure should return me the selected rows from the table.

Comment: But, I should declare the output variable right? otherwise how the list will be returned?

Comment: Not necessarily! SELECT statement in SP should returns rows when invoking procedure